# Set 2 background colors in Vuetify's card component

Tags: html, css, sass, vuetify.js

I need create login card with following design:

[image]

I want split card in half by `v-row` and `v-col` components, where left column should be some place for image and other stuff, and right column for form. When resize card to mobile version, left column should hide. Hiding column I fix with display none, but I don't know how to set each half different color.

I had idea to background color to `v-col` element, but problem is that card have rounded corners. Any idea?

My not working sample is here

https://codepen.io/peter-peter-the-typescripter/pen/KKzZVrm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` style on the `<v-row/>` element so its square corners (which overflows the card component) will be hidden.

```html
<v-card class="mx-auto" color="#26c6da" dark max-width="800" rounded="xl">
  <v-row class="mx-0" style="overflow:hidden;"> <!-- Add `overflow: hidden;` here! -->

    <!-- I've also tweaked this first column -->
    <v-col cols="6" class="yellow">
      <div class="fill-height d-flex justify-center align-center">this should be different color</div>
    </v-col>

    <v-col cols="6">
      <!-- v-card-title and v-card-action -->
    </v-col>

  </v-row>
</v-card>
```

[image]

[Here's a sample demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-archimedes-fxxkq?file=/src/components/Playground.vue)